# ¿Por qué este código no funciona como espero?

Tags: python, heroku, telegram

Tengo este problema con este código de `telethon` usando Python, la situación es que deseo que el código detecte un mensaje específico de un bot, debajo de este mensaje hay un botón el cual necesito que apriete una vez para desbloquear un enlace que te da el botón y luego leer ese enlace y enviar una parte del enlace a otro bot. El código actualmente aprieta el botón una vez pero no me envía el mensaje al otro bot. No obstante, si reenvío yo mismo el mensaje con el botón ya desbloqueado, si se acciona y me envía el enlace al otro bot.

```py
@events.register(events.NewMessage(chats='aaaaaaaa'))
async def mob_handler(event):
    client = event.client
    if 'aaaaaaa' in event.raw_text: 
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        async for message in client.iter_messages('aaaaaa', limit=1, from_user='aaaaaaa'): 
            await message.click(0)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        url = event.message.buttons[0][0].url
        await event.client.send_message('aaaaaaa', url.split('=')[1])
```

Cuando no manda el link me devuelve esto:
`await event.client.send_message('aaaaaaaa', url.split('=')[1])`

Error:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Guillermo, Bienvenido a la comunidad. Al parecer tu objeto `url` no está vacío. Puedes verificar que hay en la línea `url = event.message.buttons[0][0].url` ? al parecer no hay nada. Esto puede ser porque aún se está esperando por el resultado de la llamada asíncrona que estas realizando, por lo que valdría la pena verificar que hay en `url`

Comment: ok tengo q revisar el problema es que el me funciona si yo reenvio el mensaje con el boton desbloqueado pero si le sale el mensaje al bot y el mismo codigo lo desbloquea no funciona y me devuelve ese error